# How to remove all text but the last 3 characters

Tags: regex

I want to remove all text except the last 3 characters. So, for example if I have:

```
783223748foo
blahblahI'm
sfdhello
```

It should become:

```
foo
I'm
llo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
^.*(?=.{3}$)$
```

**Replace:**

```
(empty string)
```

The pattern `^.*(?=.{3}$)$` matches the entire line, but will then pause before consuming the final three characters in the line.  The lookahead `(?=.{3}$)` ensures that the final three characters will not be replaced.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working :/ (and yes, I have enabled RegEx lol)

Comment: Here I modified it and this works, you misplaced the dollar sign ^.*(?=.{3}$)

Comment: (in fact I think the `$` is not necessary because `*` is greedy)

Comment: I fixed it for you.. With something this simple "It's not working" is useful.

Comment: I'll test 1 sec

Comment: @JeffreyMustard "It does not replace anything" is much more useful than that in this case. "It's not working" can have multiple meaning: Does it not replace anything? Does it clear everything? Does it crash Notepad++? Does it fill the document with garbage? etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. However, with something this simple if a user says "it's not working" you could just run a simulation of it and see what happens or state that as well it's just better etiquette to test something like this, find what's wrong, and say "You should try to specify the problem better in the future."

Comment: 9 comments in 10 minutes.  Do I get a bronze badge for that?